# Searching and printing sections of file

Tags: search, grep

I have a file in the following format-

```
-----------------------
key1 = val11
key2 = val21
key3 = val31
-----------------------
key1 = val12
key2 = val22
key3 = val32
------------------------
```

I need to query by giving "key2=val22", and print the complete section (key1, key2, key3) of the matching block.

Comment: I tried using "-A" and "-B" options of grep. But, I need something which doesn't depend on the number of lines, rather depend on the section delimiters.

Comment: should this be grep only or other tools permitted ?

Comment: Using any tool should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

One of the possible ways is to do that using csplit:

```
csplit -s --prefix=mytempfile testfile '/-----------------------/+0' "{*}" \
    && cat `grep -l 'key2.*=.*val22' mytempfile*` && rm mytempfile*

-----------------------
key1 = val12
key2 = val22
key3 = val32
```

Comment: This works fine, but not so optimized for huge files I guess. Works for me though. Thank you for the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU awk with a line of dashes as the input record separator:

```
gawk -v RS='-+\n' '/\<key2 = val22\>/' file
```

I added a couple of word boundaries in there to prevent matching "the_key2" or "val229"

You can pass the key and value as parameters at the expense of a little readability

```
gawk -v RS='-+\n' -v key=key2 -v val=val22 '$0 ~ "\\\<"key" = "val"\\\>"' file
```

Comment: It'd be worth mentioning it's gawk-specific courtesy of multi-char RS and `\<` in case the OPs trying it and it's failing with their awk...